# How to retrieve values of attributes in nodelist

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, sax

for the below xml file, i want to retrieve the values of the ids the corresponds to the the lat = 53.0337395 and in the xml there are two ids with lat = 53.0337395. as shown below, to achieve this i wrote the below code but at run time i receive `#NUMBER cannt be converted into a nodelist`

please let me know how to solve it

```
String expr0 = "count(//node[@lat=53.0337395]//@id)";
xPath.compile(expr0);
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expr0).evaluate(document, 
XPathConstants.NODESET);
System.out.println(nodeList.getLength());
```

**xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<osm>
<node id="25779111" lat="53.0334062" lon="8.8461545"/>
<node id="25779112" lat="53.0338904" lon="8.846314"/>
<node id="25779119" lat="53.0337395" lon="8.8489255"/>
<tag k="maxspeed" v="30"/>  
<tag k="maxspeed:zone" v="yes"/>
<node id="25779111" lat="53x.0334062" lon="8x.8461545"/>
<node id="25779112" lat="53x.0338904" lon="8x.846314"/>
<node id="257791191" lat="53.0337395" lon="8x.8489255"/>
<tag k="maxspeed" v="30x"/> 
<tag k="maxspeed:zone" v="yes"/>
</osm>
```

Comment: `String expr0 = "count(//node[@lat=53.0337395]//@id)";` should return 2 in your case, and you are saying that 2 should be a nodeList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using a `count()` if you want to get a list of nodes (`count()` is going to return a number, not a list).  Try this instead:

```
String expr0 = "/osm/node[@lat=53.0337395]/@id";
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expr0).evaluate(document,
                                                             XPathConstants.NODESET);
System.out.println(nodeList.getLength());
```

Here is a complete compilable example using your XML file as input:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class IdFinder
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws Exception
    {
        File fXmlFile = new File("C:/Users/user2121/osm.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        String expr0 = "/osm/node[@lat=53.0337395]/@id";
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expr0).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        System.out.println("Matches: " + nodeList.getLength());
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getNodeValue());
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
Matches: 2
25779119
257791191
```